# Validando inputs php

Tags: php

Preciso mostrar todos erros no preenchimento do formulario primeiro para depois executar o FOR, porem se utilizar DIE para cada IF vai parar o script e não vai mostrar se tiver algum erro a mais, qual maneira para fazer isso?

```
if($parcelas == 0){
echo "Digite valor acima de 1 parcela para gerar<br>";
}
if($valor == 0){
echo "Digite valor acima de 0 para gerar<br>";
}
if($vencimento) {
function validateDate($date, $format = 'd-m-Y')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
if (validateDate($vencimento,'d/m/Y') == false){
    echo "Digite a data de vencimento corretamente DIA/MÊS/ANO<br>";
    die;
}
}
///Executar o for abaixo
for($i =0, $x = 1 ;$x <= $parcelas, $i <= $parcelas; $x++ ,$i++ ){}
```

Comment: Não faça isso do lado servidor, faça do lado cliente. É mais rápido, usando jQuery ou Javascript. Ou precisa ser do lado servidor ?

Comment: Na mão? Nem lembro mais como se faz em PHP ;)

Comment: existe jeito mais pratico @WallaceMaxters ?

Comment: Mais prático, levando em consideração o sistema estruturado, seria a resposta do Edilson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma simples de lidar com situações como esta seria adicionar cada erro retornado numa únca array.

```
<?php

$erros = "";

function vazio($args){
    global $erros;
    if(!empty($args) && is_array($args)){
        foreach($args as $arg){
            if(empty($_POST[$arg])){
                $erros[$arg] = $arg . " nao pode estar vazio";
            }
        }
    }
}
if(isset($_POST)){
    vazio(['nome','email','senha']);
    if($erros){
        print "<strong>Erros encontrados</strong>";
        foreach($erros as $erro){
            print "<li>{$erro}</li>";
        }
    } else {
        print "<strong>Nenhum erro encontrado</strong><br/>";
        print "Ola {$_POST['nome']}";
    }
}

?>
```

Imaginando que o formulário fosse algo assim:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="nome">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="senha">
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar">
</form>
```

A lógica é esta, logar cada erro retornado numa única array, e depois verificar se existe algum erro nessa array, caso não prossiga com a execução do script.