# Verificar campos vazios com php

Tags: php

Minha pergunta é simples, porém não estou achando uma resposta. Tenho um formulário com 5 campos, porém todos os campos são obrigatórios, em vez de eu criar empty() para cada campo, como eu faria para verificar se todos os campos estão vazios de uma só vez?

Comment: Quer fazer no JavaScript ou no PHP mesmo ?

Comment: Olá Zoom. No php mesmo.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100493/validando-inputs-php/100500#100500

Answer (score 1):

Você pode verificar campo por campo com a função
`empty()` e `is_null()` ou comparar o valor com vazio.
Porém todos de uma vez não dá.

Encontrei esse trecho de código que pode facilitar pra ti, não testei.

```
// Cria as variáveis dinamicamente
foreach ( $_POST as $chave => $valor ) {
    // Remove todas as tags HTML
    // Remove os espaços em branco do valor
    $chave = trim( strip_tags( $valor ) );

    // Verifica se tem algum valor em branco
    if ( empty ( $valor ) ) {
        $erro = 'Existem campos em branco.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos. A resposta que mais se adequou as minhas necessidades foi a do Edilson.